# Mongodb enforce index presence on insert with spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongodb collection that needs to be cleaned before a certain process starts, i do this by using `mongoTemplate.dropCollection()` method becouse it is much faster than using the deleteAll() method on the repository.

The problem arises when i introduced indexes, my model is annotated as follows:

```
@Document
public class TestModel {
    @Indexed
    private String testField;
}
```

and repository

```
public interface TestModelRepository extends MongoRepository<TestModel, String> {
}
```

This makes sure that **the index is created at application start time**

i noticed that by using the repository's deleteAll() method instead of dropping the collection preserves the index, but i was wondering if there is a way with spring-data to make sure that indexes are in place when i make an insert.

also any method to re-create indexes based on the annotated model after drop would be appreciated.

something like

```
mongoTemplate.createIndexes( TestModel.class );
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method like this

```
mongoTemplate.createIndexes( TestModel.class );
```

Before deleting, just get the indexInfo and after dropping collection, Recreate the indexes.

```
List<IndexInfo> indexInfo = mongoTemplate.indexOps(TestModel.class).getIndexInfo();

mongoTemplate.dropCollection(TestModel.class);


indexInfo.forEach(index -> {
  DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject();

  if(! index.getName().equals("_id_"))
  {
    indexOptions.put(index.getName(), 1);
    CompoundIndexDefinition indexDefinition = new CompoundIndexDefinition(indexOptions);
    indexDefinition.named(index.getName());
    mongoTemplate.indexOps(TestModel.class).ensureIndex(indexDefinition);
  }
});
```

Comment: i tried testing the original indexInfo against the indexInfo after i used this method but they look different, i think this creates a single indexInfo with multiple indexFields